# Reading a binary file in swift

Tags: swift

Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a)

```swift
        var byteArray: [UInt8] = []
        do {
            let data:NSData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
            print("Data Len: " + String(data.length))
            var buffer = [UInt8](
                unsafeUninitializedCapacity: data.length,
                initializingWith: {_,_ in}
            )
            print("Buffer Len: " + String(buffer.count))
            data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)
            byteArray = buffer
            print("Array Len: " + String(byteArray.count))
        } catch {
            print("Load Error")
            addChild(ErrorViewController())
            return
        }
```

This doesn't error but it returns a 0 length result. The printed output is:

> Data Len: 3020
>
> Buffer Len: 0
>
> Array Len: 0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
var buffer = [UInt8](
    unsafeUninitializedCapacity: data.length,
    initializingWith: {_,_ in}
)
```

does nothing because the closure does nothing (it should initialize the element storage pointed to by the first closure argument, and then set the second closure argument `initializedCount`). And this

```
data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)
```

does nothing because `buffer` is empty.

Having said that, you can simply read the file into `Data` with

```
let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as Data
// or better:
let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
```

and then work with the `Data` value. If you really need to copy the data to an array then you can do that with

```
let byteArray = Array(data)
```